# JavaScript click event not working on img when creating dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a column dynamically in a table which I am able to do.
I have an click event on an `img` tag inside a `td` tag I am creating dynamically.

I have tried with `addEventListener` and and .`onclick`.
I feel it could be because of the `outerHTML` I am using but not sure what else to use to solve this.

Below is the code:

```js
const headings = document.querySelector('thead tr');
const rows     = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

let newCellHeader = document.createElement('td');
let image         = document.createElement("img"); 
image.setAttribute("src", ""); 
            
image.addEventListener('click', onMouseOver); 
newCellHeader.appendChild(image);

headings.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<th>Test</th>');
rows.forEach((row, i) => 
  row.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newCellHeader.outerHTML)
);

function onMouseOver(e){
  console.log('++++++++++');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="content">
    <table id="pricetable" class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>Artikelnr</th><th>Produkttyp</th><th>Varumärke</th>
          <th>Pris</th><th>Antal</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>23456789</td><td>Telefon</td><td>Apple</td><td>6500</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="3" value="1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>22256289</td><td>Telefon</td><td>Samsung</td><td>6200</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="3" value="1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9898</td><td>Lorem</td><td>Ipsum</td><td>Fafa</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="3" value="2" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the click event work and fire the "onMouseOver" method and print the log statement. i.e. below method:

```
function onMouseOver(e){
console.log('++++++++++');
}
```

Comment: Just a recommendation. You are displaying an ant-pattern with your code. Saving an `image` as a `span`. Creating an `onMouseOver` function but assigning `click` to it. Just makes it more complicated for people trying to help. Try to be more consistent with your code. It will not only help yourself but other's trying to help as well!

Comment: You do not want to subscribe a separate event-handling to each newly created element within the table. But you want to let handle every event which occurs from within the table by a single function which got registered at the table's root element. It's called [event-delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

Answer (score 0):

You could do that this way...

```js
const
  pricetable = document.querySelector('#pricetable')
  headings   = pricetable.querySelector('thead tr')
, rows       = pricetable.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')
  ; 
headings.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<th>Test</th>');

rows.forEach( row =>
  {
  let newTD       = document.createElement('td');
  newTD.innerHTML = '<img src="https://picsum.photos/20">';
  newTD.addEventListener('click', click_td );
  row.prepend( newTD );
  });

function click_td(e)
  {
  console.clear();
  console.log('Last click is on row:', e.target.closest('tr').rowIndex );
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="content">
    <table id="pricetable" class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>Artikelnr</th><th>Produkttyp</th><th>Varumärke</th>
          <th>Pris</th><th>Antal</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>23456789</td><td>Telefon</td><td>Apple</td><td>6500</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="3" value="1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>22256289</td><td>Telefon</td><td>Samsung</td><td>6200</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="3" value="1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9898</td><td>Lorem</td><td>Ipsum</td><td>Fafa</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="3" value="2" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```